# Magento Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 5505024) (tried to allocate 8717 bytes) in /public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 962

Tags: magento-1.7

My Magento website is giving me the following error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 5505024) (tried to allocate 8717
>   bytes) in /public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 962

or

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 10747904) (tried to allocate
>   1280 bytes) in
>   /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate/Inline.php on
>   line 258

etc.

The website worked fine for 3 years. This problem occurred in the last 2 weeks.

What sould I do?

Comment: what's the memory limit on your server?

Comment: In .htaccess I have changed from 512 to 1024  - php_value memory_limit 1024M

Comment: @Marius Maybe your hosting provider changes some settings in the past 2 weeks. Maybe you are not allowed to change the memory limit at runtime. From the error message it does not look like the memor limit is 512M.

Comment: FYI. 10747904 bytes is 10MB - Magento should have a memory limit of at least 256MB defined.

Comment: Marius, did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Marius were you able to resolve this?